# make div dragable while hold in angular5

Tags: angular5

today i have a div which name is "title" , 
I have the task of making it move, so now I can do it in javascript with  'dragable', but I am using angular 5 and my posture is as follows :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import{ AppComponent } from '../app.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
     }
}
```

you can see my html and css in code pen https://codepen.io/__knif147/pen/yKjmao
So, i have to give it move when i hold the 'title ' div, somebody else help me please.

Comment: i found the solution is using direct in angular but angular 5 is very freshly with me. thank for give me attention.

Answer (score 0):

http://embed.plnkr.co/JbG8Si

go through this link.demo for drag and drop.
you have to install **npm** for that and put reference in app.module.ts in your project (`npm install ng2-dnd --save`) provided by angular

Comment: i just want to make div moving while i hold mouse on draggbar, but anyway, thank  for this help